# How to generate a map with density based on value, not amount of points in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggmap

I am using following data set:

```
head(trip_3)
  TIP     LON    LAT
1   0    -73.866 40.741
2   10.0 -73.906 40.707
3   1.2  -73.706 40.738
4   2.0  -73.946 40.640
5   0    -73.946 40.625
6   1.5  -73.986 40.602
```

I was able to generate following map to present points with high and low average tip values:
[image]

I have achieved it with following code:

```
nyc_map + geom_point(data=as.data.frame(trip_3), aes(x=LON, y=LAT, fill=TIP), size=3, 
shape=21, alpha=0.6, position="jitter") + scale_fill_continuous(low="white", high="#FF0033")
```

Now I want to get a map presenting areas (density) with high and low tips but not using points - I want to get something like this:
[image]

But it counts amount of points, not bases on TIP value. It would be great to achieve what I have described earlier. It is the code I used:

```
nyc_map + stat_density2d(aes(x=LON, y=LAT, fill = ..level..), size=3,
bins=10, data=as.data.frame(trip_3), geom="polygon")
```

How to make stat_density2d rely on TIP, not amount of points?

Comment: [Check out this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24198514/ggplot2-modify-geom-density2d-to-accept-weights-as-a-parameter) as I think the weighted `kde2d` version is what you're really looking to use under the hood.  As an aside, you'd likely get better/faster answers if you supply actual reproducible data/code for people to work with.

Comment: So, if it is working, perhaps you could post the solution?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generating spatial heat map via ggmap in R based on a value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45319970/generating-spatial-heat-map-via-ggmap-in-r-based-on-a-value)

Answer (score 2):

Try geom_contour. It allows you to specify a third variable as z. geom_contour will draw lines at equal TIP areas like a topographic map.

```
nyc_map + geom_contour(aes(x=LON, y=LAT, z=TIP, fill=TIP), color="white")
```

You can also use stat_contour if you want it to shade between the lines.

```
nyc_map + stat_contour(aes(fill=..level..), geom="polygon", binwidth=250, alpha=.5)
```

Here's an example. The white lines are drawn by geom_contour. The shading is done by stat_contour.

[image: Contour Example Image]