# Creating a heatmap based on values in R

Tags: r, heatmap, ggmap

I try to generate a heatmap based on values. 
Here is my dataset which consists of three variables: Lat (latitude), Lon (longitude), and Value. 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/s53xeplywz9jh15/sample_data.csv?dl=0

I have looked through the relevant posts and found this useful:
[Generating spatial heat map via ggmap in R based on a value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45319970/generating-spatial-heat-map-via-ggmap-in-r-based-on-a-value)

I copied the code in that post and here my code looks like:

```
# import data and libaries 
library(ggplot2)
library(ggmap)
Yunan<-read.csv("C:\\Program Files\\RStudio\\data\\pb_sp\\sample_data.csv", header = TRUE)

# call the map to see point distribution
Yunan_map<-get_map(location="yunan",zoom=6,maptype="terrain",scale=2)
ggmap(Yunan_map)+geom_point(data=Yunan,aes(x=Yunan$Lon,y=Yunan$Lat,fill="red",alpha=0.3,size=0.05,shape=21))+scale_shape_identity()


# 1.  generate bins for x, y coordinates (unit=decimal degree)
xbreaks <- seq(floor(min(Yunan$Lat,na.rm=TRUE)), ceiling(max(Yunan$Lat,na.rm=TRUE)), by = 0.5)
ybreaks <- seq(floor(min(Yunan$Lon,na.rm=TRUE)), ceiling(max(Yunan$Lon,na.rm=TRUE)), by = 0.5)

# 2.  allocate the data points into the bins
Yunan$latbin <- xbreaks[cut(Yunan$Lat, breaks = xbreaks, labels=F)]
Yunan$longbin <- ybreaks[cut(Yunan$Lon, breaks = ybreaks, labels=F)]

# 3.  summarise the data for each bin (use the median)
datamat <- Yunan[, list(Value= median(Value)), 
                 by = c("latbin", "longbin" )]

# 4. Merge the summarised data with all possible x, y coordinate combinations to get 
# a value for every bin
datamat <- merge(setDT(expand.grid(latbin = xbreaks, longbin = ybreaks)), datamat, 
                 by = c("latbin", "longbin"), all.x = TRUE, all.y = FALSE)

# 5. Fill up the empty bins 0 to smooth the contour plot
datamat[is.na(Value), ]$Value <- 0

# 6. Plot the contours
ggmap(Yunan_map,extent ="device") +
  stat_contour(data = datamat, aes(x = longbin, y = latbin, z = Value, 
                                   fill = ..level.., alpha = ..level..), geom = 'polygon', binwidth = 30) +
  scale_fill_gradient(name = "Value", low = "green", high = "red") +
  guides(alpha = FALSE)
```

However, I encountered two problems

1. After executing the step 3 (summarise the data for each bin), I got this error message:

   Error in `[.data.frame`(Yunan, , list(Value = median(Value)), by = c("latbin",  : 
     unused argument (by = c("latbin", "longbin"))
2. I wish to change the colour scheme from gradient to discrete colours, something like this map:

[image: sample from https://sromalewski.files.wordpress.com/2011/09/bike-share-station-suggestions-091911-913x1024.png]

Since the values in my dataset range from 17 to 21, I want to classify them  in to different bins such as 17-17.5, 17.5-18, 18-18.5.... with corresponding colours.

Any suggestions that I can fix these problems. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's because of the package ```data.table ``` the example that you're referring to uses it

Comment: I have installed this package and run the code again, but unfortunately I still go the same error.  Error in `[.data.frame`(Yunan, , list(Value = median(Value)), by = c("latbin",  :   unused argument (by = c("latbin", "longbin"))

Comment: It's this step that uses the package ```data <- setDT(read.csv(file.choose(), stringsAsFactors = FALSE))``` 

So do this ```Yunan<-setDT( read.csv("C:\\Program Files\\RStudio\\data\\pb_sp\\sample_data.csv", header = TRUE))```

Comment: That works well. Thanks. Now I will only need to how to adjust the colour scheme. The default gives equal-distance bins, which makes me hard to tell the different values.