# R: Adjusting zoom settings

Tags: r, google-maps, data-visualization, geospatial, heatmap

I am using the R programming language. I am trying to replicate the following stackoverflow post (creating geospatial heatmaps), but by using an open source map (Austin, Texas) instead of the paid version : [Generating spatial heat map via ggmap in R based on a value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45319970/generating-spatial-heat-map-via-ggmap-in-r-based-on-a-value)

Using this website here, I learned how to get an open source: https://www.reddit.com/r/Rlanguage/comments/jfnvxn/free_alternatives_for_ggmap/g9m1r4d/

The data used in this tutorial can be downloaded from dropbox (not mine, this is from the previous user):  https://www.dropbox.com/s/0s05cl34bko7ggm/sample_data.csv?dl=0.

Once downloaded from dropbox and imported into R, the data looks likes this:

```
> data = read.csv("sample_data.csv")

> head(data)
  average_rate_per_night latitude longitude
1                   $82  30.30952 -97.73171
2                  $110  30.24430 -97.77447
3                  $119  30.30038 -97.77886
4                  $105  30.27752 -97.71919
5                   $50  30.23294 -97.58938
6                  $130  30.23039 -97.76581
```

Next, the following code is run to create the entire output:

```
library(ggmap)
library(data.table)

map <- get_stamenmap(bbox = c(-97.889302,30.135824,-97.572841,30.450647))

data <- setDT(read.csv(file.choose(), stringsAsFactors = FALSE))

# convert the rate from string into numbers
data[, average_rate_per_night := as.numeric(gsub(",", "",
                                                 substr(average_rate_per_night, 2, nchar(average_rate_per_night))))]

# generate bins for the x, y coordinates
xbreaks <- seq(floor(min(data$latitude)), ceiling(max(data$latitude)), by = 0.01)
ybreaks <- seq(floor(min(data$longitude)), ceiling(max(data$longitude)), by = 0.01)

# allocate the data points into the bins
data$latbin <- xbreaks[cut(data$latitude, breaks = xbreaks, labels=F)]
data$longbin <- ybreaks[cut(data$longitude, breaks = ybreaks, labels=F)]

# Summarise the data for each bin
datamat <- data[, list(average_rate_per_night = mean(average_rate_per_night)),
                by = c("latbin", "longbin")]

# Merge the summarised data with all possible x, y coordinate combinations to get
# a value for every bin
datamat <- merge(setDT(expand.grid(latbin = xbreaks, longbin = ybreaks)), datamat,
                 by = c("latbin", "longbin"), all.x = TRUE, all.y = FALSE)

# Fill up the empty bins 0 to smooth the contour plot
datamat[is.na(average_rate_per_night), ]$average_rate_per_night <- 0

# Plot the contours
ggmap(map, extent = "device") +
    stat_contour(data = datamat, aes(x = longbin, y = latbin, z = average_rate_per_night,
                                     fill = ..level.., alpha = ..level..), geom = 'polygon', binwidth = 100) +
    scale_fill_gradient(name = "Price", low = "green", high = "red") +
    guides(alpha = FALSE)
```

The only problem is, the map that is produced from the above code is "heavily zoomed in" compared to the map from the original stackoverflow post:

[image]

I tried to fix this problem by making a bigger "box" on the map:

```
map <- get_stamenmap(bbox = c(-95.889302,28.135824,-97.572841,30.450647))
```

But this resulted in the following error:

```
Error in grid.Call.graphics(C_raster, x$raster, x$x, x$y, x$width, x$height,  : 
  Empty raster
```

Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

Thanks